# Can't compile XBMC 12 because of TAGLIB problem

Tags: linux, centos, compiling, xbmc

I am trying to compile the latest version of XBMC on CentOS 6 x64 but on `./configure` I get:

```
checking for TAGLIB... no
configure: error: Could not find a required library. Please see the README for your platform.
```

I tried compiling the taglib coming with XBMC and also downloading the latest version from github. [Both compile just fine but the error remains](http://pastebin.com/vAPdvp77).

```
[root@xbmc xbmc]# find /usr -name libtag*
/usr/local/lib/libtag.a
/usr/local/lib/libtag.so
/usr/local/lib/libtag_c.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libtag.so.1.12.0
/usr/local/lib/libtag.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libtag_c.so
/usr/local/lib/libtag_c.a
/usr/local/lib/libtag_c.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libtag.so
/usr/lib64/libtag_c.so.0
/usr/lib64/libtag.so.1
/usr/lib64/libtag.so.1.6.1
/usr/lib64/libtag_c.so
/usr/lib64/libtag_c.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libtag.so
/usr/lib/libtag_c.so.0
/usr/lib/libtag.so.1.12.0
/usr/lib/libtag.so.1
/usr/lib/libtag_c.so
/usr/lib/libtag_c.so.0.0.0
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

**UPDATE**
@slm

```
Package taglib-devel-1.6.1-1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

These are the only options configure help lists regarding taglib:

```
 TAGLIB_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for TAGLIB, overriding pkg-config
 TAGLIB_LIBS linker flags for TAGLIB, overriding pkg-config
```

Comment: git clone git://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove "taglib 1.6" installed via yum.
2. Compile and install `taglib` from Github in `/usr`.

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/
   ```
3. Edit the xbmc `configure` script by changing `ac_status=$?` to `ac_status=0` below the tests for a non-zero length of `$TAGLIB_LIBS` and `$TAGLIB_CFLAGS`:

   ```
   if test -n "$TAGLIB_CFLAGS"; then
     ac_status=0
   …
   if test -n "$TAGLIB_LIBS"; then
     …
     ac_status=0
   ```

Comment: In CentOS 6.4 i had to manually install cmake 2.8 as taglib 1.8 won't build with cmake 2.6 with some strange and cryptic errors:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:98 (file): file does not recognize sub-command COPY`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the **taglib** and **taglib-devel** libraries installed. You typically need the **-devel** of a library in order to compile against it.

```
% yum search taglib
taglib.x86_64 : Audio Meta-Data Library
taglib-devel.x86_64 : Header files, libraries and development documentation for taglib.
```

Install like this:

```
% yum install taglib-devel
```

Also notice that **taglib** is installed under `/usr/local`. Depending on your system this area may not be on the path for applications to look for it, so the `configure` command you're using to build the `makefiles` for xbmc may require you specify this location with a `--taglib=...` type of switch.

Check with `configure --help` for more info when building xbmc for the specific value.

Comment: Read the readme for xbmc, I think you need taglib > 1.8.

Comment: I updated the post. I know that I need 1.8 but the repos dont have it. And the manual build doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same problem, and the problem is tag-lib version. You have 1.6 and it requires 1.8. (check configure log). I cannot give you a solution cause I did not try anything, but "maybe", chnaging tag-lib version requirement solves compilation problem (not sure if 1.8 is really needed. Some XBMC developer should answer that.)

Comment: Sorry, did not see other replies...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether others had the same problem or not. I'm running **Centos 6.5**. I just finished building *XBMC 12.3* on it. There is no need to remove *1.6*. But after installing *1.8* from source, I had to modify the `configure` script as Giles mentioned and I also had to modify the `Makefile` for **LIBS** variable to add `-L(Taglib1.8 library path) -ltag -ltag_c`. Then, the compiling and linking works well.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I'm using Centos 7 and the problem is definitly the version of taglib.

In the configure file we have something like this.

```
pkg-config --exists --print-errors "taglib >= 1.9"
```

Which give me

```
Requested 'taglib >= 1.9' but version of TagLib is 1.8.0
```

In the configure script manually changing all 1.9 requirements to 1.8 makes it pass.

But be aware that if version 1.9 is expected their should be good reasons so perhaps this will break other peaces of code elsewhere.